# TabLayout onTabSelected not called

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm using `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` and `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in an activity.
There is no error. All tabs are displaying fines, they can be selected, swiping works.

Activity code:

```
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabLayout mSlidingTabs;
mSlidingTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mSlidingTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onPageScrolled");// nothing happens here either
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onPageSelected");// nothing happens here either
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onPageScrollStateChanged");// nothing happens here either
            }
        });
        mSlidingTabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(
                new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        super.onTabSelected(tab);
                        Log.w(TAG, "selected");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onTabUnselected");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onTabReselected");
                    }
                });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you initialise your Adapter?

Comment: yes, I have all the tabs display fine, I can select tabs, swipe among them @JoaquimLey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to perform your actions in this order:

1. Call `setupWithViewPager();
2. Add the `onTabSelectedListener();`

**Like this:**

```
mSlidingTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
mSlidingTabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(
  new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        super.onTabSelected(tab);
        Log.d(TAG, "Tab selected");
    }
});
```

If this does not work, the issue must be outside the scope of the code you provided. If that's the case please give some feedback so we can investigate further.

Comment: yes, you are right @JoaquimLey, it was already working actually, my folly only. I filtered logcat output in Android Studio that's why I didn't see the log printed out

Comment: Nice @eric I'm glad ;)

Answer (score 0):

below code tablayout & viewpager snyc

```
  pagerList.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```